# Attachements not visible in Slack Block Kit Builder

Tags: slack, slack-block-kit

I've almost copied that from Slack documentation but I can't see attachement part in Block Kit Builder. What am I missing?

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "bar"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Plain-text summary of the attachment.",
            "color": "#2eb886",
            "pretext": "Optional text that appears above the attachment block",
            "author_name": "Bobby Tables",
            "author_link": "http://flickr.com/bobby/",
            "author_icon": "http://flickr.com/icons/bobby.jpg",
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/",
            "text": "Optional text that appears within the attachment",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "title": "Priority",
                    "value": "High",
                    "short": false
                }
            ],
            "image_url": "http://my-website.com/path/to/image.jpg",
            "thumb_url": "http://example.com/path/to/thumb.png",
            "footer": "Slack API",
            "footer_icon": "https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/default_application_icon.png",
            "ts": 123456789,
            "blocks": {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slack's Block Kit Builder page does not support attachments - it's mainly meant for Blocks. Their documentation points out that Attachments are "legacy" and you should only use blocks.

Except it sucks that blocks doesn't do everything attachments does yet. Like `color` for instance. Your best bet for testing to actually post to slack, perhaps into a private channel.